# OCaml - equality of two hashtables and function with nested labelled arguments

Tags: ocaml

I want to compare two hashtables for equality:

```
open Core.Std

let hashtables_equal (x_tbl: ('a, 'b) Hashtbl.t) (y_tbl: ('a, 'b) Hashtbl.t) : bool =
  (Hashtbl.length x_tbl = Hashtbl.length y_tbl)
  && Hashtbl.for_alli x_tbl ~f:(fun ~key ~data -> Hashtbl.existsi y_tbl ~f:(fun ~k ~d -> k = key && d = data))
```

The function `f` in `for_alli` and in `existsi` has two labelled arguments `~key` and `~data`.

The code as it is above does not compile, due to using incorrect labels. However, I want to reference the `~key` and `~data` labelled arguments from within the nested function.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can give a local name to a labelled argument, you don't need to use the label itself as the name.

```
let hashtables_equal x_tbl y_tbl =
    Hashtbl.length x_tbl = Hashtbl.length y_tbl &&
    Hashtbl.for_alli x_tbl ~f: (fun ~key ~data ->
        Hashtbl.existsi y_tbl ~f:(fun ~key:k ~data:d ->
           k = key && d = data))
```

For what it's worth, there appears to be a function in Core that compares hash tables for equality:

```
let hashtables_equal x_tbl y_tbl = Hashtbl.equal x_tbl y_tbl (=)
```

The last parameter, `(=)` in this case, is for comparing elements in case the usual comparison isn't what you want. (As it wouldn't be for hash tables, as a case in point.)